# Optimal design for a database table to search for attributes

Tags: database, algorithm, binary-search-tree

Hi I hope it’s ok that I write this question here. I’m currently outlining a data structure that will sit in a database where there are movies, and each movie has a lot of descriptors.

I want to be able to search through the entire database and find movie X that has attribute, Y, Z and doesn’t have A, B, C.

What I’m thinking is to store the descriptors/attributes like this:

```
Movie ID | Attribute | Has_Attribute
1        | Action    | 0
1        | Adventure | 1
1        | Comedy    | 1
2        | Action    | 1
```

Is this the best way to store all the attributes for a record?

Presumably for every subsequent call, I would search where Action == 0 AND Comedy == 1 ... n == n_has_attribute to begin to narrow down the search.

Comment: You have binary search tree in the title but then you seem to outline a database table. I fail to see the connection. Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Normally, a database would not bother to store the `Has_Attribute` column and the one row with `Has_Attribute` set `0` wouldn't be stored.  Only those movies that have the named attribute are stored in the table at all.  One reason for this is that if you add a new attribute, your design requires you to insert a new record for each movie already recorded in the table.  Another is that your sample data is self-inconsistent — there should be two more records for movie 2 with `Has_Attribute` set `0`.

Comment: Good catch, the question went from being about processing the data to about database design, I've just updated it! @CristianBidea

Answer (score 0):

In the designing table, you do not need to store the attributes that do not exist. You need just to record the attributes that a movie has. Hence, your design would be like:

```
Movie ID | Attribute
1        | Adventure 
1        | Comedy   
2        | Action
```

Moreover, if the number of attributes is not too many, you can define them as a column in the table which has a binary value:

```
Movie Id | Adventure | Comedy | Action 
1        | 1         | 1      | 0
2        | 0         | 0      | 1
```

Therefore, to choose a better data structure, you need to clarify more the space of the problem in terms of the number of attributes, number of movies.

In addition, if you need to store the data in a decision tree, the breaking point of the nodes will be the attributes and it is more like to the second tabling architecture than the first design.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking the latter approach but want to open the system up to custom attributes. Tbd!

Comment: @DanFein Hence, the former approach by removing the `Has Attribute` column would be more suitable (the answer is updated).

Comment: Definitely. Thanks again.